# Spark shell using combineByKey with Object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, average

I have created simple dataset finding the `average`. Found the way using `tuple` with `combineByKey` option. Final result set like this `(key,(total,no.of values))`

```
scala> mydata.combineByKey( value => (value,1) , (acc:(Int,Int),value) => (acc._1+value,acc._2+1),(acc1:(Int,Int),acc2:(Int,Int))=>(acc1._1 + acc2._1 , acc2._2 + acc2._2))
res75: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, Int))] = ShuffledRDD[42] at combineByKey at <console>:36

scala> res75.take(10)
res77: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((FWA,(309,1)), (SMX,(62,1)), (BMI,(91,2)), (HLN,(119,1)), (SUN,(118,1)), (HYS,(52,1)), (RIC,(1156,8)), (PSE,(72,1)), (SLC,(8699,8)), (EWN,(55,1)))
```

Finding average value for FWA, SMX and so on, is working fine with `tuple` and `combineByKey` option.

Same thing I tried with object. Created object `fd` with two fields, `name` and `delay`.

```
scala> case class **fd**(name:String,delay:Int)
defined class fd
scala> **data**.take(2)
res73: Array[fd] = Array(**fd**(DFW,11956), fd(DTW,588))
```

In the above `RDD`, how can I use `combineByKey` option? Since it is not `key` and `value` pair.

Please suggest me the way how to find `average`? Where can I find some advanced spark programming for my study?

Comment: I can do another way like  mydata.map(s=>(s.name,s.delay)).combineByKey another option without conversion

Comment: Team have any answer for my query